# Modify a ListBox's item from a button in it's template?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, data-binding, xaml

In my Silverlight 3 project, I'm using a ListBox to display results of a Get() operation form a WCF WebService.

The ListBox's item template is the following :

```
<ListBox x:Name="m_listview" ItemsSource="{Binding Users, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" Foreground="{StaticResource EnergyBlue}" Background="{StaticResource EnergyBackground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,0,0,2" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid MinWidth="536" MinHeight="10" d:DesignWidth="19.875" d:DesignHeight="20.75">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=UserName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="{StaticResource EnergyWhite}" Margin="2" Background="{StaticResource EnergyBackground}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource EnergyBlue}" SelectionBackground="{StaticResource EnergyBlue}" SelectionForeground="{StaticResource EnergyWhite}" MinWidth="100"/>
                        <PasswordBox Password="{Binding Path=UserPass, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{StaticResource EnergyWhite}" Margin="2" Background="{StaticResource EnergyBackground}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource EnergyBlue}" SelectionBackground="{StaticResource EnergyBlue}" SelectionForeground="{StaticResource EnergyWhite}" MinWidth="100"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=UserTypeId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="{StaticResource EnergyWhite}" Margin="2" Background="{StaticResource EnergyBackground}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource EnergyBlue}" SelectionBackground="{StaticResource EnergyBlue}" SelectionForeground="{StaticResource EnergyWhite}" MinWidth="100"/>
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource EnergyGlassButton}" Grid.Column="3" MinWidth="10" MinHeight="10" Content="Update" Click="OnUpdateUser"/>
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource EnergyGlassButton}" Grid.Column="4" MinWidth="10" MinHeight="10" Content="Remove" Click="OnRemoveUser"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

The template contains 2 buttons. When I click either of them, I'd like to obtain a reference to the exact data-item under the listboxitem. How do I do that? I've tried :

```
User target_user = m_listview.SelectedItem as User;
```

but it turned out that the listview item wasn't selected. Can it be done without actually selecting the listview item? For instance, just click on the "remove" button and have the row disappear?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following ought to retrieve the Item you require:-

```
void OnUpdateUser(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
  object item = ((Button)sender).DataContext;
  // do stuff with item
}
```

Comment: Quick question that popped into my head : What if that ListBox would have been an element of a ModelView, and the button would be attached to an ICommand command? how would that have to work then?